# How to Solve Missing libintl-8.dll error with PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, installation, windows, dll, 32bit

I have Installed 32 Bit PostgreSQL 9.5 and PostGIS 2.3 on my 32 Bit Windows Desktop. I have connected to the Database via pgAdmin, and I have been able to create a PostGIS Database.

But when I try to Open the PostGIS Shapefile & DBF loader, I Get an error which says:

> The program can't start because libintl-8.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem

What do I do to solve this issue? Where Can I find this DLL?

Comment: Do you also have ArcGIS 10.4.1 Background Geoprocessing installed? It has a missing 64-bit libintl-8.dll (PostgreSQL 9.3 client)

Comment: @Vince: No; this is a fresh OS install without a Single ArcGIS product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This DLL should have been copied over by the PostGIS Installer to your PostgreSQL folder. Hence first check if it in the folder. The folder will be something like:

> C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin

If it is there, then it means that the PostGIS loader cannot find this dll, since it is in another folder.

The easiest way to solve this, is to check your PATH  environment variable, and add the PostgreSQL folder to it. Once you have added it, you should now be able to run the PostGIS Shapefile Loader.

Comment: Devdatta,

How are you running the PostGIS loader.  The libintl-8.dll should be in same folder as postgisgui so it should have been picked up without having to add PostgreSQL\9.5\bin to your search path.  Do you have it in that folder?

Comment: @LR1234567: The PostGIS loader is in the 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\postgisgui' folder, and the libntl.-8 is one folder up.

Comment: Devdatta -same problem with libintl-9,dll on 64bit version, I added the C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\ bin directory to the PATH environment and it worked

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe - Hi, When I try to run 'PostGIS 2.0 Shapefile and DBF Loader Exporter' I get a similar error but it says 'libintl-9.dll' is missing. The file is in 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin' and the PostgreSQL Binary Path is set to the same, any ideas? Thanks. EDIT - I'm using PostgreSQL 11.1 and pgAdmin 4.