# "libintl-9.dll is missing" when trying to run PostGIS 2.0 Shapefile and DBF Loader Exporter

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0, pgadmin-4

When I try to run PostGIS 2.0 Shapefile and DBF Loader Exporter I get the following error:

> The program can't start because libintl-9.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I [this previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229819/how-to-solve-missing-libintl-8-dll-error-with-postgis) which asked a similar question about libintl-8. Following [Devdatta Tengshe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/442/)'s answer I checked "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin" and the file is there:

[image]

then I checked pgadmin4's binary filepath and it's pointed at the same directory:

[image]

Where do i got from here?

Comment: @JGH - Thanks, I'll try putting it in that folder once I get an admin on the line.

Comment: copying the libintl-9.dll in **C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin** and pasting in **C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin\postgisgui** has worked! thanks

Comment: Thank you @Michiel Stas I found the libintl-9.dll file in the folder : C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\ and copied it to the folder : C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\postgisgui then ran the .exe file in that folder and it worked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It might be required in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\postgisgui` (or wherever the loader is installed).

It is however suspicious that the lib isn't included in the installer, and it might reveal other issues

Comment: This works, once that's in it also asks for libwinpthread-1.dll which just needs to be moved in as well.

Thanks.

Comment: I had the exact same issue today and moving those two files fixed it... though now I'm wary moving forward and hope this won't cause any issues down the road.

Comment: @mikeLdub - If the shapefile uploader doesn't work then you can use QGIS to load data into Postgres. Not ideal I know but still.

Comment: Copying the file into subfolder postgisgui did the trick

Answer (score 15):

I found the `libintl-9.dll` file in the folder :

`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin\`

and copied it to the folder :

`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin\postgisgui`

then ran the `.exe` file in that folder and it worked.

Comment: This worked for me as well.

Answer (score 7):

Go to C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\postgisgui (or wherever the loader is installed).
*For example, for me, C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin\postgisgui.*

Make a copy of the libintl-8.dll and paste it in the same directory.
Rename it, libintl-9.dll (with the number **9**) instead of libintl-8 - Copie.dll

Now, re-run PostGIS 2.0 Shapefile and DBF Loader Exporter (as Administrator).

You will have access to the PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export Manager.

Comment: Excellent - worked a treat.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me using PostgreSQL 14 and PostGIS 3

Answer (score 3):

That worked for me (postgresql-11.3-1-windows-x64) :

1. check that there is a libintl-9.dll in C:\Program
   Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin directory
2. add that directory to PATH environment variable (original answer
   from
   https://tutel.me/c/gis/questions/229819/how+to+solve+missing+libintl8dll+error+with+postgis)

Comment: instead of adding the libint-9.dll to environment variable, instead you can place it inside C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin\postgisgui and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Juste upgrade your PostgreSQL and your PostGIS to the last version

I got the same problem with postgreSQL 11.2 and postgis 2.5.2. Apparently this problem has been solved since then. I now run with postgreSQL 11.5 and postgis 2.5.3 and everything is fine